# Redshift SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Invalid digit, Value 'a', Pos 3, Type: Integer

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[image]
I'm suddenly getting SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Invalid digit, Value 'a', Pos 3, Type: Integer on my script which was working fine till last week. No changes have been made.

Reading online this could be due to few reasons, for e.g. NULL, decimal etc. I've checked my data and can't find any abnormal value.

There's not much help I can find to resolve this issue. Anyone familiar with this error or knows how to resolve it?

**Update:**
If I remove `::integer` from these lines (`when product_target_data_is_valid then nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_target_data, 'target_group_id')), '')::integer` ) it works fine. So I am guessing it's not casting '' to integer?

```
select
    is_valid_json(feasibility_data) as feasibility_data_is_valid,
    is_valid_json(product_target_data) as product_target_data_is_valid,
    case
            when product_target_data_is_valid then nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_target_data, 'target_group_id')), '')::integer 
    end as order_setup_target_group_id,
    case
        when product_target_data_is_valid then nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_target_data, 'category_id')), '')::integer 
    end as order_setup_category_id,
    is_valid_json(product_configuration_data) as product_configuration_data_is_valid,
    case when product_configuration_data_is_valid then
        coalesce(
            nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_configuration_data, 'behaviour_change_priced', 'action')), ''),
            nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_configuration_data, 'behaviour_change', 'action')), '')
        )::smallint
    end as order_behaviour_action_id,
    case when product_configuration_data_is_valid then
        coalesce(
            nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_configuration_data, 'behaviour_change_priced', 'noun')), ''),
            nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(product_configuration_data, 'behaviour_change', 'noun')), '')
        )::smallint
    end as order_behaviour_noun_id,
    first_value(id) over(partition by order_id order by _fivetran_deleted, created_at asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as first_id,
    --cpi_override
    case
        WHEN feasibility_data_is_valid THEN nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(json_extract_path_text(feasibility_data, 'variables_used'),'cpi_override')),'')
    END as  order_cpi_override_raw,
    case
        WHEN order_cpi_override_raw = 'true' THEN true 
        WHEN order_cpi_override_raw = 'false' THEN false
        ELSE null
    END order_cpi_override,
    *
from 
    datawarehouse.project_setup_product_setups
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**

There was an issue with underlying data. One of the ids was a string.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are getting an unexpected result from "json_extract_path_text(product_target_data, 'target_group_id')".  I recommend doing an inventory of the values of this field.  Since this is new it is likely that there are few new values crossing you up so something like this might help:

```
select trim(json_extract_path_text(product_target_data, 'target_group_id')), count(*) 
from datawarehouse.project_setup_product_setups
group by 1
order by 2
limit 1000; --hoping that the new value causing issue is only represented a few times in your data
```

Look through these, if you can, to see what won't cast to integer.  You can also try adding (after the group by)

```
having trim(json_extract_path_text(product_target_data, 'target_group_id')) like '%a%'
```

but this might not match the erroring value.

The issue could be more complex but ruling out the simple seems like the first step.